# django pages and access to parent object

Tags: django

i am running django 1.9, and i have these two simple models:

```
#models.py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

and this simply view for the answers:

```
 # views.py
 class QuestionView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'forum/question.html'
```

but now i want to build pages into the views:

```
 # models.py updated
 class QuestionView(generic.ListView):
     model = Question
     template_name = 'forum/question.html'
     paginate_by = 10
     def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk']).answer_set.all()
```

but this creates a problem, i have no longer access to the question object in the template:

```
#template.html
{{ question.question_title }}
```

how can i have both pages and access to the question object? Or do i want something now which is simply impossible?

ps. i import everything i need (generic and more), i just left them out for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add whatever data you like into a view by defining `get_context_data()`.

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(ListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs):
    context['question'] = Question.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return context
```

Alternatively, you might reflect that your original DetailView *already* gives you access to both the question - via the default object - and its answers - via `{{ object.answer_set.all }}` in the template, without having to do anything else. It seems unlikely that a question would have enough answers to need paginating, which is the main benefit that the ListView gives you.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i need. Thank you for answering